# Issue with converting string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

i'm tried to convert a string from my Database to DateTime, but some dates are invalid and i can't understand why:

for example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("7/8/2020 3:15:07 PM", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

i'm getting an error of: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

but if i try with this one:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("7/10/2020 3:15:07 PM", "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

it worked

Someone perhaps know why?

Comment: Have you tried MM and hh ? And same problem in reverse with 1 character days (pattern d instead of dd).

Comment: your first is only showing a single-digit day, but your mask is showing "dd" for two-digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"dd"` [stands for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) 2 digit day format, while you have single digit day:

> The day of the month, from 01 through 31.

Try fixing the format string (`dd` -> `d`):

> "d"
> The day of the month, from 1 through 31.

```cs
DateTime.ParseExact("7/8/2020 3:15:07 PM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

P.S.

I would recommend to store dates as dates in the database, not as strings if possible.

Comment: Thank you it fixed this issue. Now i have another issue ^^ that some dates are in totally different format like without the AM or PM or something else how can i convert everything to the same format: "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" because with the DateTime.ParseExact I'm getting error if for example i don't have the AM/PM.
Thank you

Comment: @dadou you can pass multiple formats to some [`ParseExact` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-parseexact(system-string-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles))